# Should I be writing a device driver for this?

Tags: linux, device-driver, linux-device-driver

I'm planning on a little hobby project, running on Linux on a SBC with GPIO. My idea is to generate PWM output on GPIO pins, and allow each pin to be available as a file in `/dev`, in the same way that the GPIO pins are. I would like to be able use the PWM device in the same way that the GPIO would work.

So I think I want to write a device driver, it seems to fit the bill.

The only hitch is that since I will be accessing the pins through `/dev/GPIO`, my program can exist in user space. And '*can* exist in user space' usually implies '*should* exist in userspace'.

I'm sure this could be written as a user-space daemon or a kernel-space device driver, or something else.

What's the best thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the built-in features of the microcontroller on your SBC. If you are sure there is no PWM block already established in its architecture then I guess you would need to convert a GPIO pin to do this.

[This project may be of interest.](https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/trunk/target/linux/generic-2.6/files/drivers/pwm/gpio.c?rev=21800)

Comment: I don't [necessarily] want to find something pre-written. My question is about whether or not this should be a device-driver.

Comment: you would likely be able to achieve higher resolution PWM output with a driver than say a script.

Comment: If you're talking about the language, I would most likely write it in C. My question is "should I write kernel-mode code or not". The language is not relevant to the question.

Comment: If the microprocessor does have some sort of built-in PWM, you should use it.  You would need to write kernel level code for this.  If your application requires very precise waveforms (like you are controlling motors in a robot hand) write a driver.  The simplest method, would be to write a script that controls the desired pin like a PWM.  You could do it in a few lines and it may suffice your needs.  For the greater linux community, you could put in the time to write the driver.  Hopefully, this helps and lets you know why I didn't just answer yes or no.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. I don't think the microprocessor has its own onboard PWM. It didn't occur to me that there may be timing differences between kernel/userspace. FWIW I don't need anything particularly precise, just enough to do fade lighting etc.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach towards this problem is **direct device access from user space through "/dev/mem"** file. In that case you don't need to write any driver code in the kernel space area. With "/dev/mem" file you can directly access your device with physical address from user space application.

Initial setup in user space application will be:

- Open "/dev/mem" file in Read-Write Mode (using open() system call).
- Memory map the "/dev/mem" file descriptor along with device physical address offset, to the process virtual memory address space (using mmap() system call).
- Start accessing the device with the virtual address(mmap() return
  value) of the device.

There is **risk involved** in this approach as accessing device via "/dev/mem" file is without the knowledge of Memory Manager. Other approach will be installing a device driver for your device in kernel space and then writing user space application which will be a secured device access.